# Why is there both a System.Net.Http and System.Web.Http namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Just a simple question as I'm studying the various class libraries available in .NET.  I noticed that there's a `System.Net.Http` namespace and a `System.Web.Http` namespace.

- What purpose(s) do both namespaces serve?
- What were the motivations for creating two seemingly ambiguous namespaces?
- Is there any history I should know about or is one of the namespaces "deprecated"?

[System.Net.Http](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), [System.Web.Http](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: The difference between the namespaces is that they have different members in them

Comment: I'm perhaps looking for a slightly more in-depth explanation.  See the bullet points.

Comment: (I would imagine a general taxonomy of the differences in contained classes would be relevant.)

Comment: Neither is deprecated. You typically use both of them together.

Comment: Would `System.Web` be more IIS/ASP.NET specific (as compared to Owin)?

Comment: this question need a better answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

System.Net.Http relates to network programming while System.Web.Http relates specifically to programming for the web.

Comment: Is any aspect of System.Web IIS/ASP.NET specific?

Comment: System.Web.Http and System.Net.Http are specifically implementations of the ASP.NET Web API. http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: Does that preclude them from being used in non-IIS non-ASP.NET Owin apps?

Comment: You can use whatever types are useful in any situation that they are useful in.  Certainly types that are members of System.Web and System.Net are not limited ASP.NET apps.  System.Web.Http and System.Net.Http are specifically dedicated to Web API though.  I've never used them so I'm not 100% sure but that suggests to me that they would only be useful in a Web API scenario.  That may include clients too though, which would often not be ASP.NET apps hosted in IIS.

Comment: Hmm. Isn't HTTP specific to the web?  Or am I demonstrating my ignorance?  I can't say your answer is wrong, but I'm not convinced you're right.  I also wonder about the answer from Max Toro.  Is that right?  In addition to this?  Instead of this?  Or neither?

Comment: I don't see how this answer provides any clarity at all

Comment: "The net" and "the web" are both used to refer to the Internet. This redundancy/interchangeability is presumably why the question was asked in the first place

Comment: @KyleDelaney, using "the web" to refer to the internet is incorrect because there is more to the internet than just the world wide web. Also, I didn't say "the net".  I said "network programming", which applies to any network and not just the internet. I guess my answer overestimates the computer literacy of many who want to be programmers these days. Given how many people seem incapable of even using a search engine, I guess that I should keep my expectations low. At least the OP did accept this answer so it apparently helped them.

Comment: All of the more recent answers below are excellent and you should read them ALSO. As always, there is a little more to it. :)

Answer (score 35):

System.Net.Http is for client-side HTTP programming. System.Web.Http is for server-side HTTP programming.

Comment: Is that naming convention supposed to be intuitive?

Comment: @DLeh Only if you've done work with other System.Net or System.Web namespaces, e.g. System.Net.Mail or System.Web.Mvc.

Comment: I wondered about this question when I discovered that my server code uses both namespaces.  Specifically I'm using System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage in my server. So... I shouldn't be using that class in my server?

Comment: If this answer were true  or accurate, then HttpResponseMessage would be define in System.Web.Http as opposed to System.Net.Http.  The fact is; none of  these explanations clearly describe or illuminate reasonable explanations of the differences nor the purposes of both existing nor is there a reasonable  explanation of a clear separation of functionality to facility.

Answer (score 16):

"System.Web.Http" is used for **creating** WebAPIs.

"System.Net.Http" is used for **consuming** WebAPIs (using `HttpClient` class)

Comment: this is the simplest answer i found @ReyanChougle

Answer (score 10):

From my experience, the separation between the two namespaces becomes clear when you look at the difference between self hosted webapi services vs IIS-hosted.  Self hosted only requires System.Http, whilst IIS hosted needs both.  See [Difference between "MapHttpRoute" and "MapRoute"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042853/difference-between-maphttproute-and-maproute) for a similar discussion and useful links.

So, the reason there are two is so that you can create a self-hosted web service that doesn't depend on the entire ASP.NET stack.

Neither of them are deprecated.

I haven't seen an official Microsoft explanation for this, but that's the best I've been able to find.

Answer (score 9):

System.Web heavily depends on IIS web server, which can only be hosted on a Windows machine. As Microsoft is heading to open source and is starting to support multiple platforms like Linux and Mac, they need to extract their functionality which will be independent of IIS server. As a result, System.Net is independent of IIS features and is deployable to different platforms.

Comment: Assuming this is correct, this is the most clear and concise answer. I immediately know I want to run on non-IIS servers, so I should avoid System.Web.