# How to implement multiple Get methods in WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Here I'm Trying to implement multiple Get methods but the browser througs an error `Multiple actions were found that match the request`. Why does this happen?

In the Api Controller I added two methods: 1. GetEmployee 2. HelloDept If I comment out one of them it's working fine.

```
    public class TrailController : ApiController
    {
        private IProduct Repo = new Product();

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployee()

        {
            var x = Repo.GetEmp();
            return x;

        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Department> HelloDept()

        {
            var x = Repo.GetDept();
            return x;

          }
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{api}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             //   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional }


            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code in RouteConfig.cs.

**From**:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{api}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         //   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional }


        );
```

**To**:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "API Default",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Also, refer this- [Difference between "MapHttpRoute" and "MapRoute"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042853/difference-between-maphttproute-and-maproute)

Answer (score 0):

In Your WebApiConfig.cs change

```
`api/{controller}/{id}`
```

with

```
`api/{controller}/{action}/{id}`.
```

Then call the actions like -

```
http://localhost:port/api/controller/HelloDept
http://localhost:port/api/controller/GetEmployee


public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: i make changes but no Results Same Error

Comment: Multiple actions were found that match the request: GetEmployee on type Application.Api.Controllers.TrailController GetById on type Application.Api.Controllers.TrailController HelloDept on type Application.Api.Controllers.TrailController

Comment: i make changes in Edit

Comment: it should be `api` and not `{api}`. one more thing, you're using `ApiController`, but what you posted is a `route` for `mvc`.You sure you looking at right place? It should be an `HttpRoute` in the `WebAPiConfig.cs`.

Comment: i did change also Even no Result...Wil u come on my Teamviewr

Comment: I don't have teamviewer, dude sorrry. But as you can see both the actions are being called, I believe that you are putting your code in a wrong place.